# Android Google Maps V2 get nearby gas stations and get longitude and latitude of station then draw route to it

Tags: android, google-maps

I was developing an android app with google maps V2, to get nearest gas stations with status of them if they have gas or not, now i reached to get my current location and draw route between my current location and given longitude and latitude and get the distance and duration in driving mode to that location.

My question how to get nearby gas stations, is there a way to get them and get the longitude and latitude of them, because what i want to execute is to get nearest one with the smallest distance to it and have status "have gas in it" then draw route to that location.

I was thing about scenario to execute is to get all longitude and latitude and store them into a database with status of them, and when user go to any location, it get all nearest gas station then go to database to search with status and then calculate the distance then draw the route "shortest path" of nearby station, is this the suitable way to execute or i can do with another way and if so how can i do that.

please find the code i used below and also i am testing on Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562

Map.java

```
package com.banzina;

public class Map extends Activity  implements LocationListener{

    GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    LatLng myposition;
    LatLng position2;
    float[] results = new float[1];
    TextView tvDistanceDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_map);

        tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dis);

        MapFragment fm=(MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map=fm.getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria=new Criteria(); // object to retrieve provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location!=null){
        onLocationChanged(location);

    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        map = fm.getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point){
        if(markerPoints.size()>1)            {
            markerPoints.clear();
            map.clear();
        }
        markerPoints.add(point);
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(point);
        if(markerPoints.size()==1)       {              options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));             
        }
        else if(markerPoints.size()==2)            {                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }
        map.addMarker(options);     
        position2 = new LatLng(30.08393, 31.24225);
        if(markerPoints.size() >= 2)
        {
            LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
            LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);
              String url = getDirectionsUrl(myposition, position2);
              DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
              downloadTask.execute(url);
              Location.distanceBetween(myposition.latitude, myposition.longitude, position2.latitude, position2.longitude, results);
              map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position2).title("End"));

        }
    }
        });
    }

    public void distanceTo (Location dest){}
    public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results){

    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        myposition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myposition).title("Start"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
        TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        t.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;
             String sensor = "sensor=false";
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);
                    if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                        distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                        continue;
                    }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                        duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                        continue;
                    }

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            }
            tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
        return true;
    }}
```

Layout sho_map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ShowMap" >
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"
        android:layout_marginLeft="83dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_dis"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
         android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.banzina"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.banzina.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.banzina.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.banzina.Map"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="*********My Key********" />


    </application>
</manifest>
```

DirectionsJSONParser.java

```
package com.banzina;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class DirectionsJSONParser {
     /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;
        JSONObject jDistance = null;
        JSONObject jDuration = null;


        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                  //  jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                    /** Getting distance from the json data */
                    jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                    /** Getting duration from the json data */
                    jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                    /** Adding distance object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDistance);

                    /** Adding duration object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDuration);

                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");


                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        return routes;
    }

    /**
    * Method to decode polyline points
    * Courtesy : jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
    * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                                 (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }
        return poly;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your application you will need to access a database that contains Places, examples are Google Places or Yelp for instance.

The process is the same as what you did for parsing directions. Query the API by sending an HTTP GET request to the correctly formed URL, download the returned data (most probably in JSON format), parse it and then add your `Markers`.

Links to the documentation of the APIs I have mentionned

> https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/
>   http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/overview

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i see this API will be useful but Does Google places API can response back with address or Latitude and longitude of gas stations after getting them ?

Comment: HAve you had a look at the links I gave you? Look at the bottom of this page and you'll see an example of what is returned https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Comment: Oh i missed this part, Thanks it response with formatted address and longitude and latitude this is great, will help me to solve my problem, Thanks very much

Comment: Again, like all your questions, never a upvote for your answer'er. Upvote.

Comment: bottom link is broken