# I work on my Gas_Station finder Mobile Application

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to start with the button which goes for page gets user nearest Gas_Stations according to GPS "user's locaion" , from where Could I start ?Any help is there any tutorial I can understand what is the flow of my work ?

Comment: use google places api. then implement it on your app.

Comment: can you elebarate in detail?

Comment: Okay I learn now android and I saw google maps tutorials then I find tutorial for GPS and it works right and gives me my location , now I don't know what to do , to define gas stations around me or to identify them . the output should be a list of gas stations around me the nearest ones and sofar .

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Google's Maps Api version 2.0.
Here is an old answer to this:
[Android Google Maps V2 get nearby gas stations and get longitude and latitude of station then draw route to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532982/android-google-maps-v2-get-nearby-gas-stations-and-get-longitude-and-latitude-of)